# React doesn't render but no errors in console after upgrading to react 18

Tags: reactjs

I have an app that used to work in React 17 but after I upgraded to React 18, it doesn't work, and no errors in the console.

Below of the index.js

```
import React from "react";
// import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { CompatRouter, CompatRoute } from "react-router-dom-v5-compat";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import LogRocket from "logrocket";

// redux imports
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider } from "react-redux-firebase";
import { connect, Provider } from "react-redux";
import store, { rrfProps } from "./store";

// other HOCs
import FirestoreErrorHandler from "./HOC/FirestoreErrorHandler";

// components
import App from "./App";
import SignIn from "./components/auth/SignIn";

// config checks
import runAppValidators from "./config/checks";

// run initial app validate checks
runAppValidators();

// initialize error / session-logging app
LogRocket.init("c6asae/ramcis-development");

// wait until firebase auth is ready, then render to the dom
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    authIsLoaded: state.firebase.auth && state.firebase.auth.isLoaded,
});
const WaitTillAuth = connect(mapStateToProps)(({ authIsLoaded }) => {
    // splash screen can go here in future :)
    if (!authIsLoaded) return null;
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <CompatRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <CompatRoute
                        exact
                        // path={["/", "/signin"]}
                        path="/signin"
                        element={<SignIn />}
                    />
                    <FirestoreErrorHandler>
                        <CompatRoute path="*" element={<App />} />
                    </FirestoreErrorHandler>
                </Switch>
            </CompatRouter>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
});


const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
            <WaitTillAuth />
        </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
    </Provider>
);


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Those are the changes I made for the React 18 migration

```
 import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
```

and the

```
const container = document.getElementById("root");
    const root = createRoot(container);
    
    root.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
                <WaitTillAuth />
            </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
```

I tried to use the old approach not work for me, by the way, I updated as well the routes

Below shows the screen:
[image: The console and white screen with no rendering]